# If statement and/or breaking the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a after_create statement that uses the model to create nested attributes. I am filtering days of the week boolean fields but the if statement is freezing the server (no errors).

I've included the relevant code below. For claification, sunday through saturday are boolean fields in the database. If I remove all of the "and" clauses that filter the boolean fields, the form completes, but I need to filter out dates that are not selected weekdays.

```
def new_visit  
  day = 0
  dates = (visit_date_start .. visit_date_end).count + 1
  while day <= dates
    date = visit_date_start + day
    day_of_week = date.strftime("%A").downcase
    if (day_of_week == 'sunday' and sunday == true) or (day_of_week == 'monday' and monday == true) or (day_of_week == 'tuesday' and tuesday == true) or (day_of_week == 'wednesday' and wednesday == true) or (day_of_week == 'thursday' and thursday == true) or (day_of_week == 'friday' and friday == true) or (day_of_week == 'saturday' and saturday == true)
      visits.create(:visit_price => visit_price, :visit_type => visit_type, :client_id => client_id, :visit_date => date)
      day += 1
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I've looked into the logs and once in a while, the server throws an error like below. I belive this is a sqlite locking error. Is there any more insight on this?

```
BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction
```

Comment: I think the if statement is a red herring.  Can you access those variables outside of this method, e.g. can you print them or write them to a logfile?

Comment: the days of the week are boolean fields in the database, why would they not be available? I'm not sure how to print or write them to a logfile.

Comment: Rails.logger.debug("Saturday: #{saturday}") for example.  I get that they're booleans in the DB, I'm saying I don't think the 'if' is the problem, I suspect it's the expression contained therein.  And the database fields are the most likely ones to be the problem.  :)

Comment: `p dates` would print the variable. if it is a object, array or hash, you should use `p dates.inspect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to add in an "else" clause, otherwise the method got caught waiting on what to do next. The resultant method is:

```
def new_visit  
  day = 0
  dates = (visit_date_start .. visit_date_end).count + 1
  while day <= dates
    date = visit_date_start + day
    day_of_week = date.strftime("%A").downcase
    if sunday == true
    #if (day_of_week == 'sunday') or (day_of_week == 'monday') or (day_of_week == 'tuesday') or (day_of_week == 'wednesday') or (day_of_week == 'thursday') or (day_of_week == 'friday') or (day_of_week == 'saturday')
    #if ((day_of_week == 'sunday') and (sunday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'monday') and (monday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'tuesday') and (tuesday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'wednesday') and (wednesday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'thursday') and (thursday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'friday') and (friday == true)) or ((day_of_week == 'saturday') and (saturday == true))
      visits.create(:visit_price => visit_price, :visit_type => visit_type, :client_id => client_id, :visit_date => date)
      day += 1
    else
      day += 1
    end
  end
end
```